# Tokenizing with RegEx when delimiter can be in token

Tags: c#, regex

I'm parsing some input in C#, and I'm hitting a wall with RegEx processing.

A disclaimer: I'm not a regular expression expert, but I'm learning more.

I have an input string that looks like this:

ObjectType [property1=value1, property2=value2, property3=AnotherObjectType [property4=some value4]]

(a contrived value, but the important thing is that these can be nested).

I'm doing the following to tokenize the string:

```
Regex Tokenizer = new Regex(@"([=\[\]])|(,\s)");
string[] tokens = Tokenizer.Split(s);
```

This gets me about 98% of the way.  This splits the string on known separators, and commas followed by a whitespace.

The tokens in the above example are:

```
ObjectType
[
property1
=
value1
,   
property2
=
value2
,
property3
=
AnotherObjectType
[
property4
=
some value4
]
]
```

But I have two issues:

1) The property values can contain commas.  This is a valid input:

```
ObjectType [property1=This is a valid value, and should be combined,, property2=value2, property3=AnotherObjectType [property4=value4]]
```

I would like the token after property1= to be:

```
This is a valid value, and should be combined,
```

And I'd like the whitespace inside the token to be preserved.  Currently, it's split when a comma is found.

2) When split, the comma tokens contain whitespace.  I'd like to get rid of this if possible, but this is a much less important priority.

I've tried various options, and they have all gotten me partially there.  The closest that I've had is this:

```
    Regex Tokenizer = new Regex(@"([=\[\]])|(,\s)|([\w]*\s*(?=[=\[\]]))|(.[^=]*(?=,\s))");
```

To match the separators, a comma followed by a whitepace, word charaters followed by a whitespace before a literal, and text before a comma and whitespace (that doesn't include the = sign).

When I get the matches instead of calling split, I get this:

```
ObjectType
[
property1
=
value1
,   
property2
=
value2
,
property3
=
AnotherObjectType
[
property4
=
value4
]
]
```

Notice the missing information from property4.  More complex inputs sometimes have the close brackets included in the token, like this: value4]
I'm not sure why that's happening.  Any ideas on how to improve upon this?

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Don't feel like you need to solve this using a single regex; it's perfectly fine to use multiple regular expressions to solve the problem if it makes it easier to solve.  That is unless performance becomes an issue, but I'd prefer to make it correct first.

Comment: Can the property values contain the '=', '[' or ']' characters without being a nested object? What about newlines? Basically, are you sure you can reliably parse this format at all?

Comment: It's technically possible for the property values to contain all of the delimiters, although it is unlikely.

Comment: @Patrick - this is a stupid question, but what would the approach be for multiple regular expressions?

Comment: Would you like to try a regular expression evaluator class?

Comment: Break the parsing into multiple steps, e.g. [as described here](http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch06_02.htm#perllwp-CHP-6-SECT-2.8).  However given your clarification about delimiters above I'm inclined to agree with @Brian that you might not be able to parse this reliably.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk - As long as the delimiters are escaped, it's doable. If the delimiters are not escaped, then even a human would be unable to decipher a particularly "edge-case-scenario" example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two regular expressions and a recursive function with **one caveat**: special characters must be escaped. From what I can see, `"="`, `"["` and `"]"` have special meaning, so you must insert a `"\"` before those characters if you want them to appear as part of your property value. Note that commas are not considered "special". A comma before a `"property="` string is ignored, but otherwise they are treated in no special way (and, in fact, are optional between properties).

### Input

```text
ObjectType
[
    property1=value1,val\=value2   
    property2=value2 \[property2\=this is not an object\], property3=
        AnotherObjectType [property4=some 
value4]]
```

### Regular Expressions

The regex for discovering "complex" types (beginning with a type name followed by square brackets). The regex includes a mechanism for balancing square brackets to make sure that each open bracket is paired with a close bracket (so that the match does not end too soon or too late):

```regex
^\s*(?<TypeName>\w+)\s*\[(?<Properties>([^\[\]]|\\\[|\\\]|(?<!\\)\[(?<Depth>)|(?<!\\)\](?<-Depth>))*(?(Depth)(?!)))\]\s*$
```

The regex for discovering properties within a complex type. Note that this also includes balanced square brackets to ensure that the properties of a sub-complex type are not accidentally consumed by the parent.

```regex
(?<PropertyName>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<PropertyValue>([^\[\]]|\\\[|\\\]|(?<!\\)\[(?<Depth>)|(?<!\\)\](?<-Depth>))*?(?(Depth)(?!))(?=$|(?<!\\)\]|,?\s*\w+\s*=))
```

### Code

```
private static Regex ComplexTypeRegex = new Regex( @"^\s*(?<TypeName>\w+)\s*\[(?<Properties>([^\[\]]|\\\[|\\\]|(?<!\\)\[(?<Depth>)|(?<!\\)\](?<-Depth>))*(?(Depth)(?!)))\]\s*$" );
private static Regex PropertyRegex = new Regex( @"(?<PropertyName>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<PropertyValue>([^\[\]]|\\\[|\\\]|(?<!\\)\[(?<Depth>)|(?<!\\)\](?<-Depth>))*?(?(Depth)(?!))(?=$|(?<!\\)\]|,?\s*\w+\s*=))" );

private static string Input = 
    @"ObjectType" + "\n" +
    @"[" + "\n" +
    @"    property1=value1,val\=value2   " + "\n" +
    @"    property2=value2 \[property2\=this is not an object\], property3=" + "\n" +
    @"        AnotherObjectType [property4=some " + "\n" + 
    @"value4]]";

static void Main( string[] args )
{
    Console.Write( Process( 0, Input ) );
    Console.WriteLine( "\n\nPress any key..." );
    Console.ReadKey( true );
}

private static string Process( int level, string input )
{
    var l_complexMatch = ComplexTypeRegex.Match( input );

    var l_indent = string.Join( "", Enumerable.Range( 0, level * 3 ).Select( i => " " ).ToArray() );

    var l_output = new StringBuilder();

    l_output.AppendLine( l_indent + l_complexMatch.Groups["TypeName"].Value );

    foreach ( var l_match in PropertyRegex.Matches( l_complexMatch.Groups["Properties"].Value ).Cast<Match>() )
    {
        l_output.Append( l_indent + "@" + l_match.Groups["PropertyName"].Value + " = " );

        var l_value = l_match.Groups["PropertyValue"].Value;

        if ( Regex.IsMatch( l_value, @"(?<!\\)\[" ) )
        {
            l_output.AppendLine();
            l_output.Append( Process( level + 1, l_value ) );
        }
        else
        {
            l_output.AppendLine( "\"" + l_value + "\"" );
        }

    }

    return l_output.ToString();
}
```

### Output

```text
ObjectType
@property1 = "value1,val\=value2  "
@property2 = "value2 \[property2\=this is not an object\]"
@property3 = 
   AnotherObjectType
   @property4 = "some value4"
```

---

If you cannot escape the delimiters, then I doubt even a human could parse such a string. For example, how would a human reliably know whether the value of property 3 should be considered a literal string or a complex type?

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest to answer with a lexer and parser tool. Many argue that they are too complex for these "simple" use cases, though I have always found them clearer and easier to reason about. You don't get bogged down in stupid if logic.

For C#, [GPLEX](http://gplex.codeplex.com/) and [GPPG](http://gppg.codeplex.com/) seem to be some good ones. See [here for why you might want to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282384/how-to-create-a-parserlex-yacc).

In your case you have a grammar, that is how you define the interaction between different tokens based upon context. And also, you have the details of implementing this grammar in your language and toolchain of choice. The grammar is relatively easy to define, you have informally done so already. The details are the tricky part. Wouldn't it be nice if you had a framework that could read some defined way of writing out the grammar bit and just generate the code to actually do it?

That is how these tools work in a nutshell. The docs are pretty short, so read through *all* of them, taking the time up front will help immensely.

In essence, you would declare a scanner and parser. The scanner takes in a text stream/file and compares it to various regular expressions until it has a match. That match is passed up to the parser as a token. Then the next token is matched and passed up, round and round until the text stream empties out.

Each matched token can have arbitrary C# code attached to it, and the same with each of the rules in the parser.

I don't normally use C#, but I've written quite a few lexers and parsers. The principles are the same across languages. This is *the* best solution for your problem, and will help you again and again throughout your career.